# How to keep Rails from Processing Large XML Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

In our rails application we have a many actions that do regular webapp actions. But, we have a single action that accepts a large XML file. I would like to keep rails from parsing the XML into params. Instead, I would like to be able to get the URL params ( /documents/{id}/action ) and then write out the xml file to a specific directory. How do I keep Rails from processing it?

How would I define the action to handle this?

```
def handle_xml
   # what to put here
end
```

The upload is done using Content-Type: application/xml  It is a single file, and not part of a multipart form. The sample curl statement would be:

```
curl-H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -X POST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test></test>' http://0.0.0.0:3000/controller/handle_xml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent rails from automatically parsing the XML data into a hash of parameters, you'll have to replace the ParamsParser middleware with your own custom version.

When a file is posted to rails, the ParamsParser middleware modifies the request parameters and turns it into a Hash if the data format is xml.  You can find the details in the [params_parser.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb) file in rails.

Here's a [RoR mailing list message](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/478500) similar to the question that you've asked

Unfortunately, as a new user I can't post any more links, but you should search google with "Sanitizing POST params with custom Rack middleware" for some more details on writing custom rack middleware.

Comment: That looks very good, and I can see how I can stop it from parsing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I too have come across this problem recently. However mine is in an internal application where I have full control over both the Rails app and the clients connecting to it.

In my app the client POSTs a large XML data set to the Rails app. I wanted to process the XML document in a delayed job (resque). My workaround was to make the client use an alternate content-type. I used *application/octet-stream*. This prevents Rails from parsing the POST data. The data is available in `request.raw_post`.

Comment: Looks like another good approach, we just didn't have the option to change the content type upload.

Answer (score 0):

The action should receive it as a file (through way of multipart form upload) and then store it as a temporary file for you.

Comment: What about if the file is being received as Content-type: application/xml  Is there a way to keep it from processing it? This means it isn't part of a multi-part form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sending the xml file has one variable in the http uri request?  So something like

```
@xml_file = xml..xml...xml...

parameters => {
  query => {
    xml_file => @xml_file
  }
}
Httparty.post("url", parameters)
```

Then in your method:

```
def handle_xml
  @xml_file = params[:xml_file]
  @xml_file.save (or whatever you want here..)
end
```

Comment: What about if the file is being received as Content-type: application/xml  Is there a way to keep it from processing it? This means it isn't part of a multi-part form.

Comment: good question... isn't there a way to just fool the program and say its not xml... I'll have to look into that.

Comment: You can always do a output = Hash.from_xml(@xml_file), then back_to_xml = output.to_xml